# Is there a way to import .gr2 files to Blender?

Tags: import

I want to import some 3d models in .gr2 format to edit them in Blender. Is there any add-on that does this?

Comment: According to fileext.com .gr2 files are:
"Granny by RAD Game Tools, Inc. The Granny file type is used by a number of different games, including Microsoft's Age of Empires III and other".

Iam voting to close this, as it implies copyright infringement.

Comment: because copyright infringement? as you can corroborate that I do not have a license on the use of gr2 files in addition this specifically for the use of the blender program that as far as it is free

Comment: I see no reason to close this question only because it is about something that could violate copyright laws. I think an explanation about that would be appropriate and useful to know. If the answer is no, and there are reasons for it that include copyright laws, that should be explained in an answer. The question itself is not about copyright laws, it seems to be about Blander and using a specific file format in it.